# How to leave the world of OBJ-C as early as possible and enter an existing C++ codebase in an iOS OpenGL ES app?

Tags: c++, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm looking to write an iPhone app which utilises an existing OpenGL (which will be ported to ES) code base.
I can't spend too much time invested in learning OBJ-C, so if I can limit its usage to the bare essentials (Input/OS stuff etc...) that would be great.

I know how to wrap the C++ code in opaque pointers to get the languages to play together but I need to know how to compile the C++ code (preferably within a windows environment) to be linked within X-Code. (not sure if thats the right question?)

Once it's linking I would like to know the best (earliest) way I can leave OBJ-C and get to my 'nice and happy' world of C++?

I can refine the question if this doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write C++ code or Obj-C++ (a mixture of the two languages) code at any time during your project's development. In order to get Xcode to compile the C++ correctly, you need to set the build settings in the info for your target(s) (or project). If you right click on a target and go to "info", or double click on the project in the left-hand-side pannel in Xcode and look on the "build" tab, you'll see an option "Compile Source As", which you need to set to Objective-C++. You also need to ensure that any source files with C++ code within them (or include other C++ files) are named with the extension '.mm'. This tells the compiler that there's C++ or Objective-C++ in the source file.

As far as getting to happy C++, other than the initial Objective-C code that's required to start your app and handle the AppDelegate, you could write your entire app in C++. You would miss out on all the code Apple provides in their frameworks though, which could be excedingly beneficial!

Comment: Great advice thanks. Regarding the compiling of the c++ code... would it be possible to compile the c++ code externally of XCode (ie to something like an .lib or .so) and then statically linking that library at compile time in XCode? many thanks

Comment: I do all my developement within Xcode so I'm not sure. But I know that Xcode basically uses GCC for all of it's compiling, so if you can link using GCC you can in Xcode (again, in the "build settings" in Xcode you can specify extra arguments for GCC as well as link options).

Comment: @Adam what's the advantage in not using Xcode to compile the C++?

Comment: @Richard, simply because my codebase is very large. AFAIK I would need to rename all the files to .mm? Unless you can point me to how 
I get around that? (i know i could write a script or compile step etc. but it seems unneccesary) thanks

Comment: @Adam You can leave the .cc or .cpp files as they are; Xcode's compilers (gcc and llvm) know how to make C++ compilation units interact with Obj-C++.  I guess the downside is adding all of the files to your project.

Comment: @Richard thanks for that info! I'm reading a similar thing... adding the files shouldn't be a problem as I might be able to get my environments set up to keep logical separation.